# Extended Kalman Filter - Jacobian Computation

Tags: kalman-filters

I have the following problem. I have the following Kalman filter:

$ \boldsymbol{x}_k=\boldsymbol{x}_{k-1} + \boldsymbol{w}_k$

$ \boldsymbol{y}_k=h(\boldsymbol{x}_{k}, \boldsymbol{v}_k)$

where $\boldsymbol{w}_k$ and $\boldsymbol{w}_k$ are the process and observation noises.

I would like to ask you, if $\boldsymbol{v}_k$ enters the observation equation multiplied by some elements of $\boldsymbol{x}_k$, how can I compute the Jacobians

$\boldsymbol{H}_k= \left. \frac{\partial h}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}} \right|_{\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}_{k|k-1}}$

which I need to compute the updated covariance estimate, please? Should I take the expected value of $\boldsymbol{v}_{k}$ or should I compute it as at $k-1$?
My idea was an observation equation which was something like $ \boldsymbol{y}_k=h(\boldsymbol{x}_{k}, \boldsymbol{v}_k)=f(\boldsymbol{x}_{k})+g(\boldsymbol{x}_{k})\cdot \boldsymbol{v}_k$

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The measurement noise has zero mean and is independent of the state; does that help?